# How do I add and remove CSS class on keyup in a textarea?

Tags: jquery, addclass, keyup

I asked an earlier version of this question and learned to use .css to change the class. However, I decided I'd rather use addClass and removeClass (it would make it easier for later functions I'm going to bring in).

Here is the code, and [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gEVL9/):

```
$(function(){
   if($.trim($('.text-edit1').val()).length){
      $(this).addClass('active-text');
   });
});
```

All I want to do is add a background color when the user types into the textarea, and remove the color when the text is deleted. I tried to write the beginning of the function but can't get it to work...

It would be great if anyone knew how to do this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to write `$(this)` you have to attach an event to the element. Looks like you need a `keyup` event.

```
$('.text-edit1').keyup(function () {
    if ($.trim($('.text-edit1').val()).length) {
        $(this).addClass('active-text');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active-text');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gEVL9/4/

Answer (score 2):

You can also try to attach an `keyup` event handler with jquery [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('keyup','.text-edit1',function(){
       if ($.trim($('.text-edit1').val()).length) {
        $(this).addClass('active-text');
       }
       else {
        $(this).removeClass('active-text');
      }
    });
});
```

[Try in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gEVL9/11/)

Answer (score 2):

Just a bit shorter variant, less readable.

```
$('.textarea-class').on('keyup', function (ev) {
    $(this).toggleClass('active', !!$(this).val().trim());
});
```

`!!` - will convert value to it's boolean representation

`.toogleClass(class, state)` - state "true" - class will be added, state "false" - removed

trimmed empty string `''` will be handled as falsy, so class will be removed

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RF7Sq/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `keyup` event

```
$('.text-edit1').keyup(function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).val()).length) {
        $(this).addClass('active-text');
    }else {
        $(this).removeClass('active-text');
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gEVL9/9/)

Answer (score 0):

You can `bind` keyup event with textarea.

```
$('.text-edit1').bind('keyup',function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).val()).length) {
        $(this).addClass('active-text');
    }else {
        $(this).removeClass('active-text');
    }
});
```